# Movie about gamemakers

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

It's about a small group of game developers which developed a game with some kind of demon/devil as a monster or boss. The game was in the style of the early doom or Wolfenstein. It's an old movie..

At some time, the building was struck by lightning, and this demon actually came to life! The demon slaughtered all or most of the people that were in the building.

I can't remember the ending, but it is an old movie (early 2000 maybe even before 2000.

Comment: Could you be thinking of Deadly Games, starring Christopher Lloyd as a video-game-generated demon called "The Jackal"? I know its a series rather than a movie, but I don't think it got far beyond a pilot. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111937/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_142

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How to Make a Monster"(2001)?

The game IS brought to life by a lightning strike, as in your description, and the game character does look like a demon. This was part of a series of movies produced for Cinemax by special make-up effects genius Stan Winston, called 'creature features', and they all took their titles from old '50s Roger Corman movies produced by AIP(American International Pictures). Here is the trailer from YouTube.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I've been looking for this for ages!!